# how to load xml using StreamReader

Tags: xml, streamreader

I doesn't read the XML file, it show the error like this `LoadXml(responseString)` 
"The name 'LoadXml' does not exist in the current context".I used two way to read the XML .is there an other way to read XML

```
    Stream str = null;
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(str);
  //StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(str);

    string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
  //xmlDoc.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
    responseReader.Close();
  //sr.Close();
    str.Close();
```

can any one help me to get rid out of this

Answer (score 0):

[XmlDocument.LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) loads a XML string directly.

```
xmlDoc.Load("<hello></hello>");
```

What you need is [XmlDocument.Load(TextReader)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3x426k.aspx). Note that StreamReader extends TextReader.

```
using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(str)) {
   xmlDoc.LoadXml(reasponseReader);
}
```

Comment: one doubt luis xmlDoc.LoadXml(reasponseReader) or responseReader .and also i tried not working

Comment: @Praveen04 What does "not working" mean in this context? It throws an exception? A compile error? It returns a wrong DOM? Please clarify.